# Get the rows which has max time (dt) difference

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I have a dataframe which looks like this,

```
index   bar         foo                                 foo_delta
1       2352        2020-10-21 06:26:42.889000+00:00    NaT
2       8223        2020-10-21 06:27:12.989000+00:00    00:00:30.100000
3       8723        2020-10-21 06:27:14.189000+00:00    00:00:01.200000
4       9453        2020-10-21 06:27:14.389000+00:00    00:00:00.200000
5       1342        2020-10-21 06:27:14.589000+00:00    00:00:00.200000
```

If I have to get the rows which have max(foo_delta), how would I get that?

For example, in the above dataframe max(foo_delta) is '00:00:30.100000'. So now I need to get the two rows which are responsible for max(foo_delta) i.e.

```
index   bar         foo                             
1       2352        2020-10-21 06:26:42.889000+00:00
2       8223        2020-10-21 06:27:12.989000+00:00
```

Similarly for min(foo_delta) i.e.

```
index   bar         foo                             
3       8723        2020-10-21 06:27:14.189000+00:00
4       9453        2020-10-21 06:27:14.389000+00:00
```

Can anyone help me with how we get this information in the pythonic approach?

Comment: Why is it 8723 in min ? Should not it be 1342 instead ?

Comment: The bar is a value at that timestamp, not time difference. The time difference is foo_delta.

Comment: Yes, my question was why the row at index 3 should be in output ? Do you mean the row corresponding to min and the row above that ?

Comment: Yes, the row corresponding to min and the highest row itself.

Answer (score 2):

If your data has range index as shown, you can do:

```
idxmin, idxmax = df.foo_delta.agg(['idxmin','idxmax'],)

# max values
df.loc[[idxmax-1, idxmax]]

# min values
df.loc[[idxmin-1, idxmin]]
```

In general it's safer to use `np.argmin/np.argmax` and `iloc`:

```
# remove the `NaT` value at the beginning
s = df['foo_delta'].values[1:]

# max values
idxmax = s.argmax()
df.iloc[[idxmax, idxmax+1]]

# min values
idxmin = s.agrmin()
df.iloc[[idxmin, idxmin+1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just filter the dataframe based on condition

```
df.iloc[[df.foo_delta.argmax(), df.foo_delta.argmax() - 1]]
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine and get the row that has max foo_delta. How would I get the row on top of max row? Do I need to apply shift(-1) to get both rows together?

Comment: @SakethGaruda Check now.